# How to white-list system app in doze mode (Nougat)?

Tags: android

I'm currently working on a custom ROM (based on Android 7.1.2) and have integrated an email client as a system app. It doesn't support FCM/GCM, so I need to disable battery optimization for the email sync to work reliably.

I would prefer not to ask the user to disable battery optimization (even with a dialog box).

Is there a way to white-list the email client in doze mode automatically since it is a system app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to disable battery optimization in AOSP for default apps in **frameworks_base project**, inside *data/etc/platform.xml* (example on [AOSP](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/data/etc/platform.xml) and [LineageOS](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_frameworks_base/blob/lineage-16.0/data/etc/platform.xml)).

You have to add entries as follow: `<allow-in-power-save package="my-package-name" />`

Attention: user will **NOT** be able do enable battery optimization in settings with this method.